# Spectral theorem for fractional Laplacian

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, spectral-theory

Let $(\lambda_k,\phi_k)$ be the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of the Laplacian operator ($-\Delta$) on a smooth and bounded domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R^n}$. From the spectral theorem in Hilbert spaces we know that the eigenvectors form a complete orthonormal basis for $L^2(\Omega)$. Thus for $u \in L^2(\Omega)$ we may write 
$$
u = \sum_k \langle u,\phi_k\rangle\ \phi_k \quad \text{and} \quad -\Delta u = \sum_k \lambda_k\langle u,\phi_k\rangle\ \phi_k
$$
In this setting, I have read that we can define fractional powers of the Laplacian as
$$
-\Delta^s u = \sum_k \lambda_k^s \langle u,\phi_k\rangle\ \phi_k
\quad,\quad s \in \mathbb{R} \tag{$\star$}
$$
**Questions**

- But, is ($\star$) valid for every $s \in \mathbb{R}$? Isn't the above sum diverging for certain $s \in \mathbb{R}$? Under what conditions?
- Is it true that we can find any pair $(\lambda_k,\phi_k)$ corresponding to a fractional Laplacian operator in $\Omega$ using only ($\star$) and the eigenvectors/eigenvalues of the Laplacian ($s=1$)?
- Where should I look for the regularity theory surrounding fractional Laplacians?

Pardon me for the multiple questions, but I am also asking for a reference for further study.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Whether formula ($\star$) converges depends not only on $s$ but also on $u$.  The operator $(-\Delta)^s$ is unbounded, and its domain consists of precisely those $u$ for which the sum does converge.  The spectral theorem asserts that this domain will be dense for every $s$, and the formula is "valid" for every $s$ in that it defines an unbounded self-adjoint operator.  (I'm assuming here that you want to impose Dirichlet boundary conditions, otherwise there will be some trouble with constant functions when $s<0$.)

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, I have assumed $u \in L^2(\Omega)$, but maybe the Schwartz space is more appropriate (?). Yes, I forgot to mention the boundary conditions. We can assume that it is of zero Dirichlet type.

Comment: So the answer to your first question is that for each $s$, the sum in ($\star$) will converge in $L^2$ for all $u$ in some dense linear subspace $D((-\Delta)^s) \subset L^2(\Omega)$, which varies with $s$, but will at least always contain the finite linear combinations of the eigenfunctions $\phi_k$.  I don't know if there is a more explicit characterization of which functions are in $D((-\Delta)^s)$; in general this can be very difficult.

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand your second question.  It is true that $(-\Delta)^s$ has exactly the same eigenfunctions $\phi_k$ as $-\Delta$, and that the corresponding eigenvalues are exactly the $s$ powers $\lambda_k^s$ of the eigenvalues $\lambda_k$ for $-\Delta$.  This statement is true basically by the definition of $(-\Delta)^s$ according to the functional calculus.  Is that what you were asking?

Comment: @NateEldredge When you say ' at least always contain the finite linear combinations of the eigenfunctions', do you mean that the eigenvectors, and their span, will always lie inside $D((-\Delta)^s)$ for finite $k$?

Comment: @NateEldredge Regarding the second question: yes, that's what I mean, I was just wondering why there were some posts about finding the eigenmodes of the biharmonic operator while you can work with the Laplacian and then just use formula $(\star)$.

Comment: I'm not an expert on this, but I would guess the devil is in the boundary conditions.  The spectral theorem tells you that the eigenfunctions $\phi_k$ are also the eigenfunctions for the biharmonic operator $\Delta^2$ with boundary conditions $\phi = \Delta \phi = 0$ on $\partial \Omega$.  My guess is those are not the boundary conditions that most people care about when studying the biharmonic equation.

Comment: "do you mean that the eigenvectors, and their span, will always lie inside $D((−\Delta)^s)$ for finite $k$"?  Yes indeed.  This is immediate from the definition ($\star$), because in such cases, there are only finitely many nonzero terms in the sum, so there are no worries about convergence.

Comment: @NateEldredge Why would we have to have $\phi = \Delta \phi = 0$ instead of just $\phi = 0$ on $\partial \Omega$?

Comment: I think part of the confusion is using the symbol $\Delta$ for the operator at hand, which tends to make us forget we are using a particular self-adjoint extension of the formal Laplacian, namely the one with Dirichlet boundary conditions.  So let me use $A$ to denote the Dirichlet Laplacian, where $D(A)=H^1_0(\Omega) \cap H^2(\Omega)$.  Then $D(A^2) = \{u \in D(A) : Au \in D(A)\}$.  So in order for $u$ to be in the domain of $A^2$, its Laplacian $\Delta u$ has to vanish on the boundary.  In particular this will be true for the eigenfunctions of $A^2$.

Comment: Indeed, if $\phi$ is an eigenfunction of $A$, then in particular $\phi \in D(A)$, and so trivially we have $A\phi = \lambda \phi \in D(A)$ as well.  If you pick an easy $\Omega$ for which the eigenfunctions can be written down explicitly, you ought to be able to see that $\Delta \phi, \Delta^2 \phi, \dots$ all vanish at the boundary.

Comment: @NateEldredge Does it follow that $\Delta^s \phi$ vanish at the boundary for any $s \in \mathbb{R}$?